How To Exclude URL or IP From Cache in Craft
I am working with a legacy website that uses Craft 2, which will be updated in a few months.  Until then, I am wondering if there is a way to cache "with exceptions"?
Specifically, there has been an occurrence of a different ip address being cached (it's the ip address of another site on the same web server - all go through the same load balancer).  The hosting service claim that the load balancer could not have caused this issue.
Is there a way to exclude all other URLs, other than the web site's URL from certain caching sections?
Thanks for your help in this.
Update:
Here is the code for my general.php config file:
<?php
define('URI_SCHEME',  ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) ? "https://" : "http://" );
  define('SITE_URL',    URI_SCHEME . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/');
  define('BASEPATH',       realpath(CRAFT_BASE_PATH . '/../') . '/');

 return array(

  '*' => array(
        'environmentVariables' => array(
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        'siteUrl'  => SITE_URL,
        'basePath' => BASEPATH,
        'maxUploadFileSize' => 62914560,
        //path to login template - added nov6_2017
        'loginPath' => 'login',
        ),
    'devMode' => false,    
  ),
  'dev' => array(
    'devMode' => false,
  )
 );


Sound like you've accidentally cache-poisoned yourself. A better solution than having a list of exclusions, in my opinion, is to only allow Craft to use a defined domain name. In modern versions of Craft you do this by explicitly defining the @web alias in your config. It's been a long time since I've used Craft 2 but I think you should be able to do the same thing using the siteUrl config setting (long since deprecated), and setting it explicitly to a given domain name - do not set it dynamically to "whatever the current hostname" is. That way, any invalid domain names or IP addresses will rightly result in an error response (which in turn should not get cached, depending on your caching strategy/technology).
https://craftcms.com/docs/2.x/config-settings.html#siteurl
What’s the recommended way to set the site URL?

I've updated my question to include the code for my general.php config file.
Should the second line define('SITE_URL',    URI_SCHEME . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/');
be altered?

Yep, that's what I'm saying. With that line, you're effectively saying that any hostname is a valid one. Use the siteUrl config key inside your config array instead so that you can have different siteUrls for each environment, and change each one to be static.

So, is it preferable for the static hostname to be https, or is that dependent upon site setup?

If I have only one environment, would the static url be something like 'siteUrl' => 'https://mySite.Sites.com'   ?
Or, would I need to have both, an http and https version?

Use whatever your canonical site URL is. You can only have one per environment, naturally.
